# Class Random not working as expected

Tags: vb.net, random

This block is supposed to generate a random 8 character password. When tested, it displays the same 8 characters in the textbox. If I go line by line for the entire iteration, it works properly. If I go line by line for a few loops, then let it run the rest of the characters will be repeat. For example, I break for 3 lines and then resume: abcddddd is my output.

What is causing this to happen?

```
 Private Sub generateBTN_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles generateBTN.Click
        generateTXT.Clear()
        While generateTXT.Text.Length < 9
            Dim rn As Random = New Random
            Dim num As Integer = rn.Next(33, 126)
            'disallow ();=
            While num = 40 Or num = 41 Or num = 59 Or num = 61
                num = rn.Next(33, 126)
            End While
            Dim numSTR As String = ChrW(num).ToString
            generateTXT.Text = generateTXT.Text & numSTR
        End While
    End Sub
```

Comment: There is the problem of where the random is declared.  I question the approach taken.  See my answer below for alternatives.

Comment: I edited the post and added a comment about which characters are not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare it outside of the loop and using a `Static` variable will clean up the problem. Your loop is to fast and the creation was causing to use the same seed as the others. The `Static` variable fixes that problem nicely. [`MSDN Random Class Documentation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If the same seed is used for separate Random objects, they will generate the same series of random numbers. This can be useful for creating a test suite that processes random values, or for replaying games that derive their data from random numbers. However, note that Random objects in processes running under different versions of the .NET Framework may return different series of random numbers even if they're instantiated with identical seed values.

```
Private Sub generateBTN_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles generateBTN.Click
    ' generateTXT.Clear() 'not needed
    Static rn As New Random
    While generateTXT.Text.Length < 9
        Dim num As Integer = rn.Next(33, 126)
        While num = 40 Or num = 41 Or num = 59 Or num = 61
            num = rn.Next(33, 126)
        End While
        Dim numSTR As String = ChrW(num).ToString
        generateTXT.Text = generateTXT.Text & numSTR
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, I'll be. Are you able to explain why that makes the difference?

Comment: @user287848: Random gets initialized with the current time. Make too many instances to fast and they all will generate the same sequence of numbers. That's why you should always just use one generator. Unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Well it definitely seemed like the speed of things was causing the issue.

Comment: Making the Random instance static is unnecessary.  It doesn't really help in this case, just declaring it outside the loop is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that was the advise I was given by experts awhile back - just repeating what I was taught. It does not hurt anything as far as I can see here. If it does then please explain...

Answer (score 1):

When you create an instance of Random using the default constructor (when you don't pass in anything), it uses the system time as the seed.  A specific seed will always generate the same sequence of "random" numbers.  When you create a new instance of Random in a tight loop like that, the same seed gets used for each instance because not enough time has transpired to be considered a new seed.  Therefore the calls to Next() return the same value since all the instances of Random were seeded with the same time value.

This is why you get different values when you put breakpoints in; enough time has passed between iterations of the loop to be considered a new seed value.

Typical usage of the Random class is to create **one** instance that gets reused across the whole application.  If the Random instance is to be used only within one sub, then declaring it as `static` keeps it from being disposed across runs (thus preventing the multiple instances using the same time seed problem).

Here's an alternate way to write your code:

```
Private Sub generateBTN_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles generateBTN.Click
    Dim num As Integer
    Static rn As New Random
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For i As Integer = 1 To 8
        Do
            num = rn.Next(33, 126)
        Loop While num = 40 Or num = 41 Or num = 59 Or num = 61
        sb.Append(ChrW(num))
    Next
    generateTXT.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you mean 1 to 8.

Answer (score 1):

Both previous answers have correctly identified the problem with your code as written, the random is being seeded with the same value.  A different approach to the problem results in more succinct code and that is easily maintainable.

You have a set of valid characters for the password.  They are in the ASCII range of 33 to 126 except for 40, 41, 59, and 61.  Why not write that as what it is?

```
Public Shared ReadOnly validChars As String = "!""#$%&'*+,-./0123456789:<>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"
```

Remember that a string is an array of characters.  Also, what if the users decide that "$&*,. aren't valid characters in the future?

**Method1:**

```
Public Shared PRNG As New Random
Public Shared ReadOnly validChars As String = "!""#$%&'*+,-./0123456789:<>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"

Private Sub generateBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles generateBTN.Click
    generateTXT.Text = validChars.Select(Function(c) validChars(PRNG.Next(validChars.Length))).Take(8).ToArray
End Sub
```

If LINQ is confusing to you try this.

**Method2:**

```
Public Shared PRNG As New Random
Public Shared ReadOnly validChars As String = "!""#$%&'*+,-./0123456789:<>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~"

Private Sub generateBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles generateBTN.Click
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For x As Integer = 1 To 8
        sb.Append(validChars(PRNG.Next(validChars.Length)))
    Next
    generateTXT.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```

Both do the exact same thing.  There is no conversion between numbers and characters and they don't waste cycles choosing invalid possibilities. In order to get these to match the OP's code I had to look up numbers to find out which characters were illegal.

Comment: Is the goal of your improvement only maintainability? The characters I removed will never change. Those are always invalid characters. I never want the user to be allowed to use those characters. Instead of writing them out, converting to ASCII has always been quicker and cleaner to me. I have far more valid characters than invalid characters. Naturally it would be faster to define the invalid ones. Again, this is only the case since I'm probably never going to change the invalid ones.

Comment: @user287848 - As always if the code will always be maintained by you it doesn't matter.  Technically speaking there is a remote(I know how remote) chance that all of the other posts could go into an infinite loop, what if the PRNG generates 40, 41, 59, 61, over and over and over?  I would guess that my second example is much faster than how you and the others have proposed.

Comment: Yes, a 4% chance to be exact.